# HTTP Error 404. The requested resource is not found. in Microsoft Server

Tags: .net

I am completely new to .NET, I am just trying to move my code from godaddy to another Microsoft server and in my new server. I have all the file which should be present i have also changed the connection string according to my new server space and i placed the database also correctly. My url is [Here](https://pushpdeep.pw/)

Can you help me what else i should do so that my website will become live

Comment: There may be n number of reasons for receiving 404 error. Try local deploying it first.

Comment: Which kind of .net application? Webform, MVC, webapi . Is the protocol binding correct? Is you're page listening on https?... Really many error sources